# Softmax function makes my machine to train much slower

Tags: conv-neural-network, softmax

I have two machines: CNN without softmax function and CNN with softmax function. But softmax function makes my machine to learn much slower and less accurate. Does anyone know why this happens?
Here's my code:

```
class CNN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.layer = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(in_channels=1, out_channels=16, kernel_size=5), # [batch_size,1,28,28] -> [batch_size,16,24,24]
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Conv2d(in_channels=16, out_channels=32, kernel_size=5),  # [batch_size,16,24,24] -> [batch_size,32,20,20]
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2,stride=2),                               # [batch_size,32,20,20] -> [batch_size,32,10,10]
            nn.Conv2d(in_channels=32, out_channels=64, kernel_size=5),          # [batch_size,32,10,10] -> [batch_size,64,6,6]
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2,stride=2)                                # [batch_size,64,6,6] -> [batch_size,64,3,3]
        )

        self.fc_layer = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(64*3*3, 100),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(100, 10)
        )

    def forward(self, x):
        out = self.layer(x)
        out = out.view(batch_size, -1)

        out = self.fc_layer(out)
        # out = nn.functional.softmax(out, dim=-1) # This is only different between CNN with softmax and the other one.
        return out
```

I experimented the machines with the same data (MNIST) and accuracies of the models are 98% and 88%, respectively. Here are the losses:

```
# CNN with softmax losses:
cuda:0
tensor(2.3021, device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
tensor(1.5593, device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
tensor(1.5226, device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
tensor(1.5126, device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
tensor(1.4980, device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
tensor(1.4964, device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
tensor(1.4775, device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
tensor(1.4848, device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
tensor(1.4889, device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
tensor(1.4862, device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)

# CNN without softmax:
tensor(2.3156, device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
tensor(0.2475, device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
tensor(0.1152, device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
tensor(0.1303, device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
tensor(0.0699, device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
tensor(0.0459, device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
tensor(0.0548, device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
tensor(0.0266, device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
tensor(0.0422, device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
tensor(0.0225, device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
```

Answer (score 1):

I find out what the problem is. I used Cross Entropy loss which is combined of softmax and negative log likelihood. When I use softmax with Negative log likelihood, the accuracies of two models are similar. I add my results:

```
# CNN with softmax and NLL loss
cuda:0
tensor(-0.1002, device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
tensor(-0.7444, device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
tensor(-0.7638, device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
tensor(-0.7655, device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
tensor(-0.9515, device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
tensor(-0.9763, device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
tensor(-0.9706, device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
tensor(-0.9834, device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
tensor(-0.9815, device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
tensor(-0.9782, device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)

# results:
CNN Accuracy: 98.83814239501953%
CNNwithSoftmax Accuracy: 98.4775619506836%
```

I controlled everything except loss and softmax (i.e. same training and test data, same epochs, etc.)